# How to mount directory with docker logs to docker container

Tags: docker, windows-10, fluentd, fluent-docker

I am using `Docker for Windows` on `Windows 10` with WSL

I want to collect docker logs using `Fluentd`

I figured out that docker logs on my machine store here `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\containers`

I need to bind mount this folder to `fluend` container

Any ideas for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mount docker log storage to container could be used bind mount the same as on Linux

```
volumes:
  - /var/lib/docker/containers:/fluentd/log/containers
```

Note: fluend should use the root user, indeed it will get permission deny on `/fluentd/log/containers` directory